# Building Polygon from array of points in ArcObjects and C#

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I have seen [this code in ArcPy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Polygon/000v000000n1000000/) which is used to create a Polygon from a string of Points(X , Y).

Can you let me know how I can us something like this to generate a polygon from an array of X,y values in C# and ArcObjects?

I have already taken a look at [ArcObjects 10 .net framework sample code sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002wm000000) of Building a Polygon Using Points but it was too confusing for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it.  There's probably a better way.

```
void IPointCollection makePC(List<IPoint> pList)
{

IGeometryBridge2 pGeoBrg = new GeometryEnvironment() as IGeometryBridge2;
IPointCollection4 pPointColl = new PolylineClass();
int numPoints = pList.Count; 
WKSPoint[] aWKSPointBuffer = new WKSPoint[numPoints];
for(int i =0; i < pList.Count; i++)
{
WKSPoint A = new WKSPoint();
A.X = pList[i].X;
A.Y = pList[i].Y;
aWKSPointBuffer[i] = A;
}
pGeoBrg.SetWKSPoints(pPointColl, ref aWKSPointBuffer);

return pPointColl; 
}
```